# Formatting the grouping of a report print template

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2017, report-designer

I building a print template for a permitting service. In that template, I have one dataset(with about 15 properties).I am working with Visual Studio 15, using the Report Designer that is built in.

Because I have to Print all the permit info that is returned in a search, I am using a list, then dragging each property into the it. (I have tried using Matrices, and Tables, but they don't print out all of the permits returned.) I am trying to organize the data by one of the properties (i.e. CountyNumber) in the dataset, then insert a page break when that property changes.

However, when I try to configure the default row group "Details" to group on the CountyNumber Property, the result is that I get the first permit with each CountyNumber. Does anyone have any hints as to what I need to get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem, I ended up having to create a parent group for the "Details" group. I was able to then configure the "Group On" expression to the CountyNumber property.

I also had to remove any other grouping properties I had tried to set. In the Sort screen for the Parent Group, I set it to sort on the CountyNumber, and on the Sort screen for the "Details" group I sorted by the permit number field.

I then set the Page Break window on the Details group to break between groups. 
Not sure why the page break had to be set on the child group, but it worked. Maybe if some one could answer that I would feel better about the answer I came up with?